# Arclength-Parametrized Space Curve Inequality

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, frenet-frame

Give any arclength parametrized space curve $\alpha(s)$  (where space curve just means its codomain is $\mathbb R^3$), I want to show the following inequality:

$$\lVert \alpha(s) \rVert ≥ \lvert \alpha(s) \cdot N(s) \rvert$$

where $N(s)$ is the principal normal vector of $\alpha$.

I'm pretty sure this is true, as I can't think of any counterexamples, but I can't come up with a proof. So how can I do prove this? Or alternatively, if it's not true, under what conditions is it true?

Comment: Since $N$ is a unit vector this is just the [Cauchy-Scwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) written in the reverse order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Recall the dot product formula $${\bf x} \cdot {\bf y} = ||{\bf x}||\,||{\bf y}|| \cos \theta ,$$ where $\theta$ is the angle between ${\bf x}$ and ${\bf y}$.